# Angular translate giving key when upgraded to WKWebview for localization

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-translate, ionic-v1

We are working on ionic application which support ionic-v1. For translation we use **$translate**. The issue is when using **$translate.use() and $translate.instant()** its giving key instead of proper value.

Note: This issue we are facing after we upgrade the **cordova-iOS to 6.0 from UIwebview to WKWebview**, once downgrade the cordova-iOS back to 5.0 its working as expected and all are scripts are in **scripts/locales** folder.

Below was the working code.:

```
en.js // locale file

{
 "APP_NAME_LABEL": "My app name",
}

script.js //controller js file

$translate.use('en').then(function (translation) {
        $scope.viewTitle =$translate.instant('APP_NAME_LABEL');
});
```

**Expectation**: should give value '**My app name**' of "**APP_NAME_LABEL**" key from locale file.
**Reality** : giving key "**APP_NAME_LABEL**" instead of value

Could anyone let me know what to do to resolve it.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found out that's a problem with CORS/Security from the new WKWebView.
TO solve that, you should define a schema and a hostname in your config.xml file.

I solved the issue adding this to the config.xml file

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```